# Fastlane ios beta fails with error No provisioning profile found for app identifier 'com.website.AppName'

Tags: xcode, react-native, fastlane

X error: No profiles for 'com.website.AppName' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.website.AppName'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppName')

```
platform :ios do
  desc 'Setup Apple Certificates'
  lane :certificates do
    match(type: "appstore", app_identifier: "com.website.AppName", readonly: true)
  end

  desc 'Build the iOS application and push to Testflight.'
  lane :beta do
    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY_ID"],
      issuer_id: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_ISSUER_ID"],
      key_content: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY"],
      duration: 1200,
      in_house: false
    )
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "./ios/AppName.xcodeproj")
    build_app(workspace: "./ios/AppName.xcworkspace", scheme: "AppName")
    upload_to_testflight(api_key: api_key, skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)
    commit_version_bump(message: "Version Bump", xcodeproj: "./ios/AppName.xcodeproj")
  end
end
```

Comment: This helped me https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18182#issuecomment-777628923

Comment: All you have to add a profile from `xcode/preferences/Accounts`

Comment: @Robin can you please explain more in detail and put it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem today using Fastlane to build a QA version for AppCenter. The cause ended up being an outdated Ruby version. I updated Ruby to v3.1 and everything ran smoothly again.

There are probably other ways to do this, but one way to update Ruby is to use brew:

1. `brew install ruby@3.1`
2. `brew link --force --overwrite ruby@3.1`
3. Restart terminal
4. `ruby --version` to make sure the update worked